# Display overlay on button submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to disable a button on my form when the user clicks it but it's not firing at all.

I set the ID to submit to match the function but it's not firing. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using WebPortalSite.MiscClasses
@using WebPortalSite.sessions
@model WebPortalSite.Models.PaymentModel.CheckPayment

    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Checking / Savings Account Information";
    }
    
    @if (CurrentCustomerSession.Current.TokenShowHideSettings.ShowPaymentScreenMessage)
    {
      <div class="CompanyMessage">
        @Html.Raw(@CurrentCustomerSession.Current.TokenSettings.PaymentScreenMessage)
      </div>
    }
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AchPaymentSubmit", "Payment", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Please fill out the fields below. All fields are required.</legend>
    
    
          <div class="paymentPageMargin">
    
            <div class="check_paymentBlock">
    
              @if (CurrentCustomerSession.Current.CurrentCustomer.BudgetRate > 0)
              {
                <div class="block_container">
                  <div class="serviceBox1 paymentBlockTextLeft payment-label-nomargin">
                    Budget Rate:
                  </div>
                  <div class="serviceBox2 paymentBlockText payment-label-nomargin">
                    $@($"{CurrentCustomerSession.Current.CurrentCustomer.BudgetRate:F2}")
                  </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="block_container">
                  <div class="serviceBox1 paymentBlockTextLeft payment-label-nomargin">
                    Budget Balance:
                  </div>
                  <div class="serviceBox2 paymentBlockText payment-label-nomargin">
    
                  </div>
                </div>
    
              }
              else
              {
    
                <div class="block_container">
                  <div class="serviceBox1 paymentBlockTextLeft payment-label-nomargin">
                    Account Balance:
                  </div>
                  <div class="serviceBox2 paymentBlockText payment-label-nomargin">
                    @($"{CurrentCustomerSession.Current.CurrentCustomer.TotalBalance:F2}")
                  </div>
                </div>
              }
    
            </div>
    
            <div>
              @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "All fields are required. Please fill the highlighted fields below.")
            </div>
    
            <!-- BUSINESS OR PERSONAL ACCOUNT -->
            <label for="PaymentType" class="paylabel payinput width600">
              <span class="payspan">Account Type:</span>
    
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CheckType, "Personal", new { @class = "" }) Personal
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CheckType, "Business", new { @class = "" }) Business
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CheckType)
            </label>
    
            <!-- CHECKING OR SAVINGS SELECTION -->
            <label for="PaymentType" class="paylabel payinput width600">
              <span class="payspan">Payment Type:</span>
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AccountType, "Checking", new { @class = "" }) Checking
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AccountType, "Savings", new { @class = "" }) Savings
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountType)
            </label>
    
            <!-- CARD HOLDER'S NAME -->
            <label for="CardHoldersName" class="paylabel width400 newline">
              <span class="payspan">Name on Check</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NameOnCheck, new { @class = "payinput width400", @maxlength = "20", autocomplete = "off", id = "CardHoldersName" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NameOnCheck)
            </label>
    
            <!-- BILLING PHONE -->
            <label for="PhoneNumber" class="paylabel">
              <span class="payspan">Phone Number</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "payinput", @maxlength = "12", autocomplete = "off", id = "PhoneNumber" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
            </label>
    
            <!-- BILLING STREET -->
            <label for="StreetAddress" class="paylabel width400 newline">
              <span class="payspan">Street Address</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StreetAddress, new { @class = "payinput width200", @maxlength = "20", autocomplete = "off", id = "StreetAddress" })
            </label>
    
            <!-- BILLING CITY -->
            <label for="City" class="paylabel width400">
              <span class="payspan">City</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "payinput width200", @maxlength = "20", autocomplete = "off", id = "City" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City)
            </label>
    
            <!-- BILLING STATE -->
            <label for="billingstate" class="paylabel newline">
              <span class="payspan width300">State or Province of Account</span>
              @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, SelectListItemHelper.GetProvincesList(), new { @class = "payinput paycombobox", id = "billingstate" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.State)
            </label>
    
            <!-- BILLING ZIP -->
            <label for="Zip" class="paylabel">
              <span class="payspan">Zip</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "payinput", @maxlength = "6", autocomplete = "off", id = "Zip" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Zip)
            </label>
    
            <!-- CHECK NUMBER -->
            <label for="CheckNumber" class="paylabel newline">
              <span class="payspan">Check Number</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckNumber, new { @class = "payinput", @maxlength = "10", autocomplete = "off", id = "CheckNumber" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CheckNumber)
            </label>
    
            <!-- CHECK ROUTING NUMBER -->
            <label for="CheckRoutingNumber" class="paylabel">
              <span class="payspan">Routing / transit number</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckRoutingNumber, new { @class = "payinput", @maxlength = "9", autocomplete = "off", id = "CheckRoutingNumber" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CheckRoutingNumber)
            </label>
    
    
            <label for="CheckAccountNumber" class="paylabel newline">
              <span class="payspan">Account number</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckAccountNumber, new { @class = "payinput", @maxlength = "17", autocomplete = "off", id = "CheckAccountNumber" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CheckAccountNumber)
            </label>
    
    
            <label for="CheckAccountNumber2" class="paylabel">
              <span class="payspan">Re-enter account number</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckAccountNumber2, new { @class = "payinput", @maxlength = "17", autocomplete = "off", id = "CheckAccountNumber2" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CheckAccountNumber2)
            </label>
    
            <br />
    
            <label for="payamount" class="paylabel">
              <span class="payspan">Payment Amount</span>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, "{0:F2}", new { @class = "payinput width90", @maxlength = "8", autocomplete = "off", id = "payamount" })
            </label>
    
            @if (@Model.FeeAmount > 0)
            {
              <label for="CheckNumber" class="feelabel">
                <span class="payspan"> + @Model.FeeAmount.ToString("C") Processing Fee</span>
              </label>
            }
    
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)
    
            <br />
            <div class="paymentButton newline">
              <p>
                <input id="submit" class="typicalbutton" type="submit" value="Continue" />
              </p>
    
              <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                  $(".submit").button({ disabled: true });
    
                  $(document).submit(function () {
                    $(".submit").button({ disabled: false });
                    document.getElementById('<%=submit.ClientID%>').value = 'Processing...';
                  });
    
                });
              </script>
    
    
    
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    
      <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.FeeAmount)
      </div>
    
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you need to tag jQuery, and it would be great if you'd abstract out the template code and provide a working demo using the editor.

Comment: I don't think [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#events) has a `submit` event, though. You probably should be using a form and its submit event.

Comment: It's hard to make an accurate comment looking at this code. I guess first fault, you don't have form. second you are trying to make enable button in submit event. you have to enable or disable button with some validation, not in submit event.

Comment: @isherwood Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @gokhancevik I've provided the entire set of code. I didn't before to make the post more simplistic. Hope that helps!

Comment: JavaScript acts on rendered HTML. Please show that and not your templating. I'm not sure what you want an example of. Forms have submit events, so use a form.

Comment: @isherwood what do you mean `using the editor`?

Comment: What you see after you click the edit button (link) above.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="paymentButton newline">
      <p>
        <input id="submit" class="typicalbutton" type="submit" value="Submit Payment" />
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');

        $(document).submit(function () {
          $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', true);
          document.getElementById('<%=submit.ClientID%>').value = 'Processing...';
        });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry but I replace what I had with this and it made no difference.